# Lightbox plugin use issue

Tags: jquery

I'm using the [Lightbox_me](http://buckwilson.me/lightboxme/) plugin in a project of mine. It seems quite simple, therefore my choice. The problem is that it's invokation it's not working as expected.
The author's example:

```
$('#try-1').click(function(e) {
    $('#sign_up').lightbox_me({
        centered: true, 
        onLoad: function() { 
            $('#sign_up').find('input:first').focus()
            }
        });
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

My adaptation:

```
$('.compositos_DBitem').on('click', function(e){
  $('.compositos_DBitem_lightbox', this).lightbox_me({
      centered: true
    });
  e.preventDefault();
});
```

... it doesn't work. Any ideas?
Full code here: [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/5WapL/).

Thanx.

Pedro

Comment: which jqeury version you are using right now ?

Comment: I'm using jQuery 1.9.1.

Comment: It require jQuery version 1.4.2

Comment: Try using [jQuery UI dialog](http://jqueryui.com/dialog/#modal-confirmation), it has similar function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use jQuery Migrate to work with that older lightbox plugin. `jQuery.browser is deprecated` as it says in console.

See updated fiddle with jQuery migrate added.

[demonstration with jQuery migrate plugin](http://jsfiddle.net/5WapL/1/)

Read more about jQuery Migrate [here](http://blog.jquery.com/2013/05/01/jquery-migrate-1-2-0-released/)

Comment: I'll have to use another one then. Thanx.

Answer (score 1):

jQuery 1.9 doesn't support [$.browser](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.browser/)

> Description: Contains flags for the useragent, read from navigator.userAgent. This property was removed in jQuery 1.9

Try an older version of jQuery, or a newer version of the plugin.

Answer (score 1):

You have to migrate lightbox plugin because `$.browser` is no more supported. Or downgrade your jquery version:

http://jsfiddle.net/5WapL/2/

BTW, initialize a new lightbox on each click is not a good practice and only can bring you some issues.